# Laravel many-to-many-to-many throught relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database, eloquent

I am developing a Laravel web app with a kind of hard to solve through-relationship. My relationship looks like this:

[image]

The problem is: I want to have a `courses` relationship on my `module` model. I tried to solve it with a custom has-many relationship that works ... kind of. Well, yes, it works, but only if I access it directly. If I tried to use this relationship with something like `whereHas('courses')` it fails and builds an incorrect query. I can work around this by using `whereHas('module_numbers.courses')`, but actually, that's not the way I want it to be – if there is a better solution, that I haven't found yet.

Any pro ideas on how to solve my problem?

My current "solution":

```php
public function courses() {
  $query = (
    Course::query()
      ->select('courses.*')
      ->join(
        "course_module_number",
        "courses.id",
        "course_module_number.course_id"
      )
      ->join(
        "module_numbers",
        "course_module_number.module_number_id",
        "module_numbers.id"
      )
      ->join(
        "modules",
        "module_numbers.module_id",
        "modules.id"
      )
      ->distinct()
  );

  return $this->newHasMany(
    $query,
    $this,
    $this->getForeignKey(),
    $this->getKeyName()
  );
}
```

EDIT (2022-01-17): changed database schema:
[image]

Comment: Are mdoule Number and course_module number needed? All you really need is one table between courses and modules. Course_Module can have one and only one Course but a course can have many Course Modules. An a Course_Module can have one and only one module but a module can have many Course_Modules. Which would jsut contain the primary key of Courses and Modules UPDATE: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.ddi.doc/ids_ddi_186.htm

Comment: I think you're better off using `whereHas('module_numbers.courses')`. I think there are some packages that add this kind of deep relationships, but I can't vouch for them as I've never felt the need to use them.

Comment: @Wakka I will think about your comment. I just try to imagine if there is a case, where the teaching form type differs for different module numbers of a module. I guess not. In this case it would make things a lot easier.

Comment: Okay, after thinking about this: no, I cannot simplify the relationships: A module can have many module numbers. But a course can be offered for all module numbers of a course, but it doesn't have to. Therefore I need a table between module numbers and courses :/

Comment: The usual answer for this kind of question is to use this package. I can't vouch for it but I've seen it turn up in a lot of answers. https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Comment: @Gregor, This is exactly how you combat Many to Many though. All you need is one table between modules and courses.

Comment: @Wakka not really: I don't want to add a new pair of (module_id, module_number_id) each time I create a new course. This stuff is kind of stable and seldomly changes.

Comment: @Gregor, Well if kind of stable and a broken relationship is your thing. Really you should jsut solve your Many to Many relationship with an intersect entity. Again another example https://www.relationaldbdesign.com/database-design/module6/convert-manyToManyRelationships-into-oneToManyRelationships.php. This is RDB 101 to be honest.

Comment: @Wakka I just realised that I don't need a relationship between `modules` and `courses` through `module_numbers`, but a relationship between `modules` and `courses`, and a relationship between `modules` and `module_numbers`. I guess, that's what you wanted to tell me.

Comment: @Gregor You will still have th solve the M:n issue with `courses` and `modules` as a Course can have many Modules and a Module can have many Courses. Look at the example for intersect to solve it. As for `module_numbers`, is it really needed just to store the module id separate from the modules entity?

Comment: @Wakka I am totally not sure what you mean with the m:n problem: I have `modules`, I have `courses`, and I have a relationship table `course_module` with two columns: `course_id` and `module_id`. Therefore I have a 1:n relationship between `modules` and `course_module`, and I have a 1:n relationship between `courses` and `course_module`. Isn't it that what you want to tell me?

Comment: @Wakka I uploaded my current partial database schema. I cannot split the table `course_module` into separate tables without unnecessary duplications of data.

Comment: @Gregor, That's you sorted it by the looks of it.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this as following

In your Course model

```php
//import Module model

public function modules(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Module::class);
}
```

In your Module model

```php
//import Course model

public function courses(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class);
}
```

Now you can access using eagerloading as follows

```php
$courses = Course::with('modules')->get();
```

```php
$modules = Module::with('courses')->get();
```

OR

use it with `has` if you want get as with at least one data

```php
$courses = Course::has('modules')->get();
```

```php
$modules = Module::has('courses')->get();
```

Now you can use `foreach` or if you want to access relationship you can do following

```php
 foreach($courses as $key => $value){
   $value->modules->credit_points
 }
```

OR for `module`

```php
 foreach($modules as $key => $value){
   $value->courses->semester
 }
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But this is only possible with my new schema. With the old schema this was a lot harder to do. Thanks anyway!